# intellij idea community edition - sql auto complete in Java?

Tags: sql, intellij-idea

I see that Intellij community edition does not support sql tools (according to this comparison: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html?IC).

Is there any plugin that enables SQL auto complete / syntax highlighting in java code?
As described here - "SQL in Other Languages": http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/database_tools.html

Comment: AFAIK, there is no third-party plug-in that can do it.

Comment: The link shows an image illustrating that you can. Maybe this changed since you posted this question? http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/database_tools.html

Comment: here you can see that database tools are supported only in ultimate edition: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html?IC